# Getting rid of space under relative div with negative margin-top

Tags: html, css, margin

I have some kind of animated javascript slider. I wan't some items to stick out a little of the top of my slider but to be hidden when they stick out of the bottom of the wrapper, so i made a div with overflow:hidden; with a little extra space over it. I now need to get rid of that extra-space in the flow.

It wasn't a problem before because i'd just set the div as absolute but now i'm making my layout fluid and i can't have absolute divs because the slider's height is relative to the document's width. Is there any way to get rid of those extra-pixels ? Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/ySg6f/
Here's the actual website if it can help : http://pa3com.a3net.fr/

```
<header>
<div id="slider_wrapper">

    <div class="overflow">
        <div id="slider">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

```
header
{
    padding-top:20px;
    background-color:blue;
}
#slider_wrapper
{
    position:relative;
    background-color:green;
}
.overflow
{
    padding-top:12px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#slider
{
    height:0;
    padding-bottom:25%;
    background-color:red;
    top:-12px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: with extra space you mean the blue stripe in your fiddle?

Comment: I think he is talking about the green!? Solution: `#slider {margin-bottom: -12px;}`

Comment: No the green one, the blue space is for the menu over my slider over which some animated elevents might fly ;)

Comment: Margin-bottom:-12px DID get rid of the space, but it also made the .overflow div a little smaller, so now my items are disapearing too soon :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it by using negative margin and adding 1px padding on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
.overflow {
 padding-top: 0;
}

#slider {
 top: -12px; /* remove this */
}
```

Comment: I need this extra space to display other elements within the .overflow div.

Comment: @Jean-Georges in that case, give .overflow `{ padding-bottom: 20px; }`, that is if you are using `position: absolute;`, otherwise it'll automatically expand according to your content.

Comment: I can't use absolute positing because the slider needs to expand depending on it's content height.

Comment: @Jean-Georges then what is the problem? It'll expand according to its content, why do you want this `space`?

Comment: I need this extra space but it must be invisible. Take a look at the actual slider, you'll see that some elements stick out of the slider top.